# Handle DBNull in an object initializer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, initialization, asmx, dbnull

In my asp.net web service, I have an object class which get data from database, but I counter the following problem when some data is null in database:

(1) If I don't handle the NULL value in database and use the code as below:

```
<WebMethod> _
Public Function GetCustomerDetail(ByVal sqlQuery As String) As List(Of customerInfo)
    Dim detaillist = New List(Of customerInfo)()
    Dim detail As customerInfo

    Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn)
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        detail = New customerInfo() With { _
         .CustomerID = dr("CUSTOMER_ID"), _
         .CustomerName = dr("CUSTOMER_NAME"), _
         .RegisterDate = dr("REGISTER_DATE"), _
         .Address = dr("ADDRESS") _
        }
        detaillist.Add(detail)
    Next
    Return detaillist

End Function

Public Class customerInfo
    Public CustomerID As String = String.Empty
    Public CustomerName As String = String.Empty
    Public RegisterDate As String = Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    Public Address As String = String.Empty
End Class
```

I got the error:

System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.

(2) if I handle the NULL in database as below:

```
<WebMethod> _
Public Function GetCustomerDetail(ByVal sqlQuery As String) As List(Of customerInfo)
    Dim detaillist = New List(Of customerInfo)()
    Dim detail As customerInfo

    Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn)
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        detail = New customerInfo() With { _
         .CustomerID = dr("CUSTOMER_ID"), _
         .CustomerName = dr("CUSTOMER_NAME"), _
         .RegisterDate = dr("REGISTER_DATE"), _
         If dr("ADDRESS") = System.DBNull.Value Then
            .Address = ""
         Else
            .Address = dr("ADDRESS") _
         End if
        }
        detaillist.Add(detail)
    Next
    Return detaillist

End Function

Public Class customerInfo
    Public CustomerID As String = String.Empty
    Public CustomerName As String = String.Empty
    Public RegisterDate As String = Date.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    Public Address As String = String.Empty
End Class
```

I got the error:

Compiler Error Message: BC30985: Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'.

I want to know how to handle the DBNull value for string and date in an object initializer.

Comment: You can't use an if statement in an object initializer like that

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Convert.ToString

```
<WebMethod> _
Public Function GetCustomerDetail(ByVal sqlQuery As String) As List(Of customerInfo)
    Dim detaillist = New List(Of customerInfo)()
    Dim detail As customerInfo

    Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn)
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim registerDate As Date
    If Date.TryParse(Convert.ToString(dr("REGISTER_DATE")), registerDate ) = False Then 
    'Do what you need to do if the cell is not a valid date time value
    End If
        detail = New customerInfo() With { _
         .CustomerID = Convert.ToString(dr("CUSTOMER_ID")), _
         .CustomerName = Convert.ToString(dr("CUSTOMER_NAME")), _
         .RegisterDate = registerDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), _
         .Address = Convert.ToString(dr("ADDRESS"))
        }
        detaillist.Add(detail)
    Next
    Return detaillist

End Function
```

Edited based on OP's comment below.

Comment: Hi Quannt, the date value still contains the time value (for example 12:00:00), how to display the data as  dd/MM/yyyy only? thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot Quannt, but after update the code it cause error. There is something wrong because .RegisterDate = registerDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") never mention the field naem "REGISTER_DATE".

Comment: @MapleLi no nothing's wrong with that because registerDate is already assigned using Date.TryParse. What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

While the other methods would work, I think a re-usable extension method with generics support would be ideal.

You can pass the work off to the extension method and check if the value is equal to the value of `DBNull.Value`

```
Public Module DataRowExtensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function GetValueOrDefault(Of TExpectedType)(dr As DataRow, propertyName As String) As TExpectedType
    If DBNull.Value.Equals(dr(propertyName)) Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Return DirectCast(dr(propertyName), TExpectedType)
    End Function
End Module
```

You can see this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wH3SDQ) to see it in action with various data types.

Do make note that the extension method `Field<T>` does exist and is similar, but it doesn't handle `DBNull` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an if statement inside an object initializer like that.
You have to instantiate the object, then set the properties in separate lines.

```
detail = New customerInfo() 
'Then in separate lines, populate the properties individually

If dr("ADDRESS") = System.DBNull.Value Then
    detail.Address = ""
Else
    detail.Address = dr("ADDRESS")
```